# Multi Level Nested Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use a multi level toggle option in my code.

For that I am using this [**plugin**](http://smartik.ws/2013/11/smk-accordion-free-jquery-plugin/) .

In that plugin I didn't find the  `multi level toggle`. Can any one help me with this plugin to use multi level toggle.

Please tell me with this plugin, because I have customised it a lot. So if you recommend a different plugin it will be more difficult for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/99JbF/5/

Comment: share the relevant part of your code, i.e. on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Added the code on jsfiddle.net

Comment: @MichalLeszczyk http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265257/1947286

Answer (score 0):

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xanetia/8kz4m/) link.

Check this [link](http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/jquery/nested_accordion.html) also. In this they given 5 different Nested Accordion demos.

The following code shows Multilevel Jquery Accordion

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Initialising Accordion
$(".accordion").tabs(".pane", {
    tabs: '> h2',
    effect: 'slide',
    initialIndex: null
});

//The click to hide function
$(".accordion > h2").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("current") && $(this).next().queue().length === 0) {
        $(this).next().slideUp();
        $(this).removeClass("current");
    } else if (!$(this).hasClass("current") && $(this).next().queue().length === 0) {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
        $(this).addClass("current");
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your information. But I need to use with above plugin. can you download my plugin and tell me the code i need to add where?.

Answer (score 0):

You have not included **Js** and **Css** file in your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99JbF/4/)

Css:

http://smartik.ws/downloads/free_demo/scripts/smk_accordion/css/smk-accordion.css

Js:

http://smartik.ws/downloads/free_demo/scripts/smk_accordion/js/smk-accordion.js

[**Check Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NXTnt/)

Your js Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $(".accordion_example1").smk_Accordion();
        $(".accordion_example2").smk_Accordion({
            closeAble: true,
        });
        $(".accordion_example3").smk_Accordion({
            showIcon: false,
        });
        $(".accordion_example4").smk_Accordion({
            closeAble: true,
            closeOther: false,
        });
        $(".accordion_example5").smk_Accordion({
            closeAble: true
        });
        $(".accordion_example6").smk_Accordion();
        $(".accordion_example7").smk_Accordion({
            activeIndex: 2
        });
        $(".accordion_example8").smk_Accordion();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You want multi level toggle. I think you want this type of answer.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/NXTnt/1/)

HTML code

```
<div class="container_demo">
        <div class="accordion_example2">

            <!-- Section 1 -->
            <div class="accordion_in">
                <div class="acc_head ">Heading1</div>
                <div class="acc_content">
                    it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. 

                       <div class="accordion_example3"> 
                        <div class="accordion_in">
                            <div class="acc_head ">Inner Heading1</div>
                            <div class="acc_content">
                                it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                           <div class="accordion_in">
                            <div class="acc_head ">Inner Heading2</div>
                            <div class="acc_content">
                                it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Section 2 -->
            <div class="accordion_in">
                <div class="acc_head" >Heading1</div>
                <div class="acc_content">
                    it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. 

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Section 3 -->
            <div class="accordion_in">
                <div class="acc_head" >Heading2</div>
                <div class="acc_content">
                    it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. 
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        $(".accordion_example2").smk_Accordion({
            closeAble: true, 
        });

        $(".accordion_example3").smk_Accordion({

        });

    });
```

Comment: Yes. But inner toggle open and closes immediately. can you try it and give a proper code.